# How do I set clicked state for my custom button?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I made my own background for a button and I want the button to change when it is clicked.
I found this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/boutonnpousse" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/boutonn"/>
</selector>
```

But where do I use it? I tried just pasting it in main XML file but it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will save this as an xml file in `res/drawable` folder. If this folder does not exist, create it. In the example, the file name that I use is `selector_drawable_name.xml`

Following this, whenever you use a Button, and want it to have the click effect, set its background to this drawable:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_drawable_name" />
```

Result: When the button's state changes to `state_pressed`, the background selected will be `@drawable/boutonnpousse`. Default (in every other state) will be `@drawable/boutonn`.

Comment: Yes! Works perectly. Thank you very much! I'm new to Android programming, so whenever a thing like this isn't explained with enough details, I get lost :)

Comment: @Matthew No problem at all. Hope the explanation made sense.

Comment: So how do you change the colour of the button text in its highlighted state? ie: if it's black when it's unselected but white when selected?

Comment: @Marchy For that, you need a `ColorStateList`. Add a xml file (say `button_color.xml`) in `res/color` folder. Create this folder if it isn't there. The file contents will look very similar to what user `Whiz` has in the question. Make these changes: Replace `android:drawable="@drawable/XXXXXX"` with `android:color="@color/XXXXXXX"`. This way, you can have different text colors for different states.

Comment: @Marchy Oh, and don't forget to reference this newly created file in `android:textColor="@color/button_color"` for the intended `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

By the way...you can use the state list XML generator in the following site:

http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.il/p/android-state-list-generator-v2.html

Just check the states you would like to add and assign drawable file names in the corresponding fields at the bottom. The generator will generate the XML elements in the right order using the right states.